# JS not loading on production server rails ec2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

**My JS from the homepage is not loading on my production server it is working fine in local and development mode.
here is my code snippet**

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
<div class="slider-content">
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://www.101corpuschristi.com/media/cache/articlepage_main/uploads/media/default/0001/18/891e375d4758a612dc949cf1fd4b9e33d0c401d9.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 img-h" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://www.esva.net/~daiseys/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/IMG_2096-1536x1152.jpg" class="d-block w-100 img-h" alt="...">

    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
         <img src="https://www.101corpuschristi.com/media/cache/articlepage_main/uploads/media/default/0001/18/891e375d4758a612dc949cf1fd4b9e33d0c401d9.jpeg" class="d-block w-100 img-h" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
   <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container mb-5 mt-2">
  <div class="row booking-box">
    <div class="col-md-7"> </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="card shadow">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h1 class="card-title">Booking</h1>
           <%= form_with url: "/filter_packages", method: :get do |form| %>

            <div class="form-group">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-layer-group"></i>
              <%= form.select :name, options_for_select(Service.all.pluck(:name).map { |key| [key.humanize, key] }),{prompt: 'Select Category', selected: '', disabled: ''}, class: "form-select",required: true %>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
              <%= form.select :location_name,options_for_select(ServiceLocation.all.pluck(:location_name).map { |key| [key.humanize, key] }),{prompt: 'Select Beach Location', selected: '', disabled: ''}, class: "form-select", id: 'locations-select' ,required: true%>
              <%= link_to 'Check Location Details', '#', id: 'show-location-button', style: 'display: none;', class: "text-decoration-none ml", onclick: "show_location_details()" %>
            </div>
        

            <div class="form-group" style="width:106%;">
              <%= form.date_field :setup_time, selected: Date.today, min: Date.today, max: 2.year.from_now, class: "form-select", required: true, id: 'date-select' %>
              <%# <%= form.date_field :setup_time, selected: Date.today, min: Date.today, max: 2.year.from_now , class: "form-select" ,required: true , id: 'date-select'  %> 
            </div>
            
             
            <div class="form-group">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-clock"></i>
              <%= form.select :setup_time_slot, options_for_select([], nil),{prompt: 'Select Time-Slot', selected: '', disabled: ''}, class: "form-select", id: 'setup-time-slot-select' %>
              <%# <%= form.select :setup_time_slot, options_for_select(ServiceLocation.setup_time_slots.keys.map { |key| [key.humanize, key] }), {}, class: "form-select" %>
            </div>
              
             <div class="actions" style="margin-top: 20px;">
              <%= button_to 'Book Now', packages_path, method: :get, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            </div> 

          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <!-- <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCalmy6jQmJysfyzpxExVmCdIf-YzbMQPc&libraries=places&callback=Function.prototype" async defer></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10.15.5/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<style>

.carousel-control-prev, .carousel-control-next{
  width: 40px!important;
  height: 40px!important;
  border-radius: 50%!important;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.06) !important;
  font-size: 35px!important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  top: 220px !important;
  color: white!important;
    }
  .carousel-control-next-icon {
      height: 15px!important;
      font-size:20px!important;
  }
   .carousel-control-prev-icon {
      height: 15px!important;
  }
.ml{
  text-align: right;
}
.footer{
  margin-top:72px;
}
.img-h{
  height:520px;
}
  .card.beach-details .card-body ol {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 14px;
}
.card.beach-details .card-body ol li {
    color: #000;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}
 .card.beach-details .card-body h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
    letter-spacing: -0.5px;
}
.card.beach-details .card-body h5.card-title {
    margin: 0 0 3px 0;
    color: #1074bc;
    font-size: 24px;
}
.card.beach-details .card-body p.card-text {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    font-weight: 400;
}

.card-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.form-group i{
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  left: 10px;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 7px;
}
.form-select {
  padding-left: 30px!important;
}

.form-select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.slider-wrapper{
  position:relative;
}
.slider-content{
  position:absolute;
  top:-8px;
  width:100%;
}
.booking-box{
  padding-top: 60px;
}

  .slider-content .img-h{
    object-fit: cover;
  }
@media(max-width: 576px){
  .slider-content{
    position: unset;
  }
.booking-box{
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
.ml {
      text-align: right;
}
}
.carousel-indicators{
  display:none;
}
a.button:not(.disabled):hover, a.button:link:not(.disabled):hover, a.button:visited:not(.disabled):hover, input[type=submit]:not(.disabled):hover, input[type=button]:not(.disabled):hover, button:not(.disabled):hover {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    background-image: none !important;
}
 a.button:not(.disabled):active, a.button:link:not(.disabled):active, a.button:visited:not(.disabled):active, input[type=submit]:not(.disabled):active, input[type=button]:not(.disabled):active, button:not(.disabled):active {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
</style>


<script>

function initMap(data) {
  if (data != null)
  { 
    var allLocationsMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("allLocationsMap"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(data.latitude,data.longitude),
      zoom: 10
    });
  
   
    console.log("allLocationsMap",allLocationsMap)
    <% ServiceLocation.all.each do |location| %>
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(<%= location.latitude  %>, <%= location.longitude %>),
        map: allLocationsMap
      });
      // Add a click event listener to the marker
       marker.addListener("click", function() {
        allLocationsMap.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        allLocationsMap.setZoom(12);

        // Set the content of the info window with the location information, images, and "Get Directions" button
        var content = '<div class="card beach-details">' +
          '<div class="card-body">' +
          '<div class="shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">' +
          '<h5 class="card-title"><%= location.location_name %></h5>' +
          '<p class="card-text"><%=  location.location_details %></p>' +
          '<p class="card-text"><%=  location.beach_details.to_s.html_safe %></p>' +

        // Loop through the images and create <img> elements
           '<div class="beach-image">';
        <% location.thumbnails.each do |thumbnail| %>
          content += '<img src="<%= url_for(thumbnail) %>" style="width: 100%; height: auto; cursor: pointer;" onclick="zoomImage(this)">';
        <% end %>
        content += '<button onclick="window.open(\'https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/<%= location.latitude %>,<%= location.longitude %>\')" class="btn btn-primary mt-2">Get Directions</button>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>' +
          '</div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: content
        });

        infowindow.open(allLocationsMap, marker); // Open the info window at the marker's position
      });
     <% end %>
  }
}

  // Call initMap when the page finishes loading
  // window.addEventListener("load", initMap);

  // Call initMap again when navigating through the navigation bar
  document.addEventListener("turbo:load", initMap);

  if (!sessionStorage.getItem('firstVisit')) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('firstVisit', 'true');
    location.reload();
  }


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#locations-select').change(function() {
    $('#show-location-button').show();
     var selectedLocation = $('#locations-select option:selected').val();

      // Customize the popup content (you can use any HTML here)
      var popupContent = `<h1 class="card-title">Choose a Location on the Map</h1>
      <p class="card-text"><small>Explore real images and get directions</small></p><div id="allLocationsMap" style="height: 400px; width:auto;"></div>`;

    fetch(`/services/search?location_name=${selectedLocation}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    })
   .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(result => {
         // Show the popup using SweetAlert
      Swal.fire({
        html: popupContent,
        confirmButtonText: 'Close',
        didOpen: () => {
          initMap(result); // Initialize the map after the popup is opened
        }
      });
      
      });
      /*resultsContainer.innerHTML += '</ul>';*/
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
  });
  
  $('#show-location-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
    
    var selectedLocation = $('#locations-select option:selected').val();
 // Customize the popup content (you can use any HTML here)
      var popupContent = `<h1 class="card-title">Choose a Location on the Map</h1>
      <p class="card-text"><small>Explore real images and get directions</small></p><div id="allLocationsMap" style="height: 400px; width:100%;"></div>`;

    fetch(`/services/search?location_name=${selectedLocation}`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    })
   .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      data.forEach(result => {
         // Show the popup using SweetAlert
      Swal.fire({
        html: popupContent,
        confirmButtonText: 'Close',
        didOpen: () => {
          initMap(result); // Initialize the map after the popup is opened
        }
      });
      
      });
     /* resultsContainer.innerHTML += '</ul>';*/
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
   });

});

    // Initialize the locations array with data from Rails
    var locations = <%= raw ServiceLocation.all.to_json %>;
    const dateSelect = document.getElementById('date-select');
    const setupTimeSlotSelect = document.getElementById('setup-time-slot-select');

  // Define the setup time slots once
    const setupTimeSlots = ['10:00 am - 10:30 am','11:00 am - 11:30 am','12:00 pm - 12:30 pm', '1:00 pm - 1:30 pm', '2:00 pm - 2:30 pm', '3:00 pm - 3:30 pm', '4:00 pm - 4:30 pm', '5:00 pm - 5:30 pm', '6:00 pm - 6:30 pm', '7:00 pm - 7:30 pm'];

    dateSelect.addEventListener('change', function() {
    const selectedDate = this.value;
    console.log("check here man",selectedDate)
    // Clear the existing options
    setupTimeSlotSelect.innerHTML = '';

    // Get the current date and time
    // const currentDate = new Date();
    // const currentTime = currentDate.getHours() + ':' + ('0' + currentDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

    const currentDate = new Date();
    let hours = currentDate.getHours();
    let minutes = ('0' + currentDate.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    let meridiem = 'AM';

    if (hours > 12) {
      hours -= 12;
      meridiem = 'PM';
    }

    const currentTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + meridiem;

    // Filter out past time slots if the selected date is today
    const filteredTimeSlots = (selectedDate === '<%= Date.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>') ? setupTimeSlots.filter(timeSlot => timeSlot >= currentTime) : setupTimeSlots;
    console.log("filteredTimeSlots",filteredTimeSlots)
    // Populate the setup time slot select field with the filtered options
    filteredTimeSlots.forEach(function(timeSlot) {
      const option = document.createElement('option');
      option.value = timeSlot;
      option.text = timeSlot;
      setupTimeSlotSelect.add(option);
    });
  });

    function zoomImage(imageElement) {
      imageElement.style.maxHeight = "100vh";
      imageElement.style.maxWidth = "100%";
      imageElement.style.position = "absolute";
      imageElement.style.top = "0";
      imageElement.style.left = "0";
      imageElement.style.zIndex = "99999";
      imageElement.onclick = function() {
        imageElement.style.maxHeight = "auto";
        imageElement.style.maxWidth = "100%";
        imageElement.style.position = "static";
        imageElement.style.zIndex = "0";
        imageElement.onclick = function() {
          zoomImage(imageElement);
        };
      };
    }
</script>
```

**here are my logs from web console**

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://18.116.70.46/services/new' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element 'https://18.116.70.46/assets/blue-a52a2a75a004fcc7dbe2f54b5e24c81f9423c151101679c91d5a49ec5578c684.png'. This request was not upgraded to HTTPS because its URL's host is an IP address.
owl.carousel.min.js:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
components.css:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
utilities.css:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
bootstrap.bundle.min.js:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
base.css:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
js?key=AIzaSyCalmy6jQmJysfyzpxExVmCdIf-YzbMQPc&libraries=places:233 Google Maps JavaScript API has been loaded directly without a callback. This is not supported and can lead to race conditions and suboptimal performance. For supported loading patterns please see https://goo.gle/js-api-loading
pda @ js?key=AIzaSyCalmy6jQmJysfyzpxExVmCdIf-YzbMQPc&libraries=places:233
owl.carousel.min-5965c76b27c18adb0bfa1e5def04df6fa48a2a425b426dd973a308037378325d.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fn')
    at owl.carousel.min-5965c76b27c18adb0bfa1e5def04df6fa48a2a425b426dd973a308037378325d.js:6:21377
    at owl.carousel.min-5965c76b27c18adb0bfa1e5def04df6fa48a2a425b426dd973a308037378325d.js:6:21982
new:231 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://18.116.70.46/services/new' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element 'https://18.116.70.46/assets/blue-a52a2a75a004fcc7dbe2f54b5e24c81f9423c151101679c91d5a49ec5578c684.png'. This request was not upgraded to HTTPS because its URL's host is an IP address.
js?key=AIzaSyCalmy6jQmJysfyzpxExVmCdIf-YzbMQPc&libraries=places&callback=initMap:237 You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
jda @ js?key=AIzaSyCalmy6jQmJysfyzpxExVmCdIf-YzbMQPc&libraries=places&callback=initMap:237
new:537 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
js?key=AIzaSyCalmy6jQmJysfyzpxExVmCdIf-YzbMQPc&libraries=places&callback=initMap:153 Uncaught (in promise) InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function
    at _.Cg (js?key=AIzaSyCalmy6jQmJysfyzpxExVmCdIf-YzbMQPc&libraries=places&callback=initMap:153:471)
    at oda (js?key=AIzaSyCalmy6jQmJysfyzpxExVmCdIf-YzbMQPc&libraries=places&callback=initMap:234:186)
    at js?key=AIzaSyCalmy6jQmJysfyzpxExVmCdIf-YzbMQPc&libraries=places&callback=initMap:233:15
application-6a44a2ae…01c5e00cefccc3.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
application-6a44a2aefa28bf0e9c530aa2f05a575ef9f89a1a916ca48e3901c5e00cefccc3.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (application-6a44a2aefa28bf0e9c530aa2f05a575ef9f89a1a916ca48e3901c5e00cefccc3.js:16:20)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2:27244)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2:28057)
    at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2:29891)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2:30257)
js?key=AIzaSyCalmy6jQmJysfyzpxExVmCdIf-YzbMQPc&libraries=places:231 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'St')
    at js?key=AIzaSyCalmy6jQmJysfyzpxExVmCdIf-YzbMQPc&libraries=places:231:121
base.css:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
components.css:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
utilities.css:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

**The assets not found issue is still there on some next pages but the JS is loading on them I have tried solving all issues from the console I succeded in cutting them to last 2 but still issue is there.**

**Here are production logs**

```
I, [2023-10-04T06:32:01.968996 #508632]  INFO -- : [246c93fc-ade2-459f-9b19-9d2c600240aa] Started GET "/services/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-10-04 06:32:01 +0000
I, [2023-10-04T06:32:01.973236 #508632]  INFO -- : [246c93fc-ade2-459f-9b19-9d2c600240aa] Processing by ServicesController#new as HTML
I, [2023-10-04T06:32:01.987642 #508632]  INFO -- : [246c93fc-ade2-459f-9b19-9d2c600240aa]   Rendered services/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 13.5ms | Allocations: 4586)
I, [2023-10-04T06:32:01.990119 #508632]  INFO -- : [246c93fc-ade2-459f-9b19-9d2c600240aa]   Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 16.0ms | Allocations: 5854)
I, [2023-10-04T06:32:01.990555 #508632]  INFO -- : [246c93fc-ade2-459f-9b19-9d2c600240aa] Completed 200 OK in 17ms (Views: 14.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms | Allocations: 6120)
```